# Magento 1.9 - multiple helpers in module

Tags: php, magento, module, magento-1.9

i have a question about setup multiple helpers in my module. The normal config.xml looks like this:

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <MyPackage_Helper1>
            <class>MyPackage_HelperClasses_Helper1</class>
        </MyPackage_Helper1>                                    
    </helpers>
</global>
```

In general I would add a Data.php in MyPackage/HelperClasses/Helper with something like this:

```
class MyPackage_HelperClasses_Helper1_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

And then i can load the helper via `Mage::helper('MyPackage_Helper1')`

If i have only one helper this works fine. But how is the setup of multiple helpers? And is there a way to seperate each helper in his own file (so instead of Data.php i want to use something like Helper1.php, Helper2.php etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Multiple helpers in your module, you can specify the helper class name in lowercase letter like below:

Mage::helper('MyPackage_Helper1/helper1')

OR

Mage::helper('MyPackage_Helper1/helper2')

When we don't specify any class name, Magento use `data` class name by default. You can check the function `getHelperClassName` in `Mage_Core_Model_Config` class.

Comment: Ok and how than does the config.xml looks like?

Comment: MyPackage_Helper1 node is for identify the helper folder path. Then After we specify the helper class name. So there is no change in config.xml. But you can give some good single letter name to helper node

Comment: Ok so just to be sure. I have a Data.php in the Helper folder. And in the Helper folder i can put in my helpers (Helper2.php for example). And then i can call the helper by Mage::helper('MyPackage_Helper1/helper2'). And the Helper2.php is something like: MyPackage_HelperClasses_Helper2

Comment: Helper class name will be like `MyPackage_HelperClasses_Helper_Helper1` or `MyPackage_HelperClasses_Helper_Helper2`